# How to console each slider value only when they are moved?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-slider

I have 3 slider ranges:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" id="time" >
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      Days: <b>1</b> <input id="days" type="text" class="span2" value="" data-slider-min="1" data-slider-max="31" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="[0,31]"/> <b>31</b>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      Months: <b>January</b> <input id="months" type="text" data-provide="slider" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="12" data-slider-tooltip="show" data-slider-value="[0,12]" /> <b>December</b>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      Years: <b>0</b> <input id="years" type="text" class="span2" value="" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="2017" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="[0,2017]"/> <b>Today</b>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I am running the following js:

```
var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
getData = function() {
    var data = {};
  var temp = $('#days').slider().val().split(',');
  data.days = temp[0];
  temp = $('#months').slider().val().split(',');
  data.months = months[temp[0]];
  temp = $('#years').slider().val().split(',');
  data.years = temp[0];
  console.log(data);
}
$("#days, #years").slider({
  tooltip: 'always',
});  
$('#months').slider({
    formatter: function(value) {
    return months[value[0]] + " : " + months[value[1] - 1];
    }
});
$("input").on("slide", function(slideEvt) {
    getData();
});
```

Basically when we move a `slider`, the console outputs the current `value` of the current `value` and output is:

```
{days: "12", months: "July", years: "1396"}
```

That is fine but if I move the second slider because I want to do a range, the second value isn't showing while it should be:

```
{days: "12", days: "24", months: "July", months: "September", years: "1396", years: "1842"}
```

But each value or both, should only appear when we actually move each `slider`

Here it is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pz3ce0o6/1321/), check console

**Note**, I am actually going to need the values with this format as they will be considered as classes for some elements:

Example

```
day22 
february
year1632
```

Comment: Objects cannot have duplicate keys.

Comment: @trincot so how can we do it? Can we push them as two different arrays anyhow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects cannot have duplicate keys, so you'll have to use a different data structure. You could for instance let `data` be an array of two objects, and then each of those two objects would have a day, month and year property:

```
getData = function() {
    var data = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        data.push({
            day: $('#days').slider().val().split(',')[i], 
            month: months[$('#months').slider().val().split(',')[i]],
            year: $('#years').slider().val().split(',')[i], 
        }) ;
    }  
    console.log(data);
}
```

Or, if you prefer to have the days together in a pair, and the same for the months and years, you could let each of those three properties be an array with two values:

```
getData = function() {
    var data = {
        days: $('#days').slider().val().split(','), 
        months: $('#months').slider().val().split(',').map(i => months[i]),
        years: $('#years').slider().val().split(',')
    }  
    console.log(data);
}
```

#### Another issue

The months slider is allowing one value too many (there are 13 values between 0 and 12 inclusive), so you need to make this change to the month slider properties:

```
data-slider-max="11"
```

and in the code:

```
$('#months').slider({
    formatter: function(value) {
        return months[value[0]] + " : " + months[value[1]]; // not -1
    }
});
```

Comment: OK, please note that there is something wrong with your month slider (which confused me while answering). It allows 13 values. See the update of my answer.

Comment: ok yes perfect, it works https://jsfiddle.net/jikupin/pz3ce0o6/1333/ thank you very much

Comment: one very last one question, let's say that we have svg paths with the same classes as per the values we get, I'd like to do     `$("input").on("slide", function(slideEvt) {
      getData();
      $("svg path").hasClass() {
        $(this).addClass("active");
      }
    });` what would I put inside `.hasClass()` ?

Comment: also note that because we cannot have css classes with numbers, I had to use `"day" + number` and `"year" + number` so they are `day22` and `year1954`

Comment: I am not sure what you want to do...`hasClass` will return a boolean. Did you intend to write `if (......hasClass(.....))`? Or do you want to filter for elements that have the class? In that case you need `.filter`. Anyway, for this purpose it would be better to use still another data structure for `data`: just a plain array with 6 string values (the classnames for 2 days, 2 months and 2 years).